# Get Previous/Above Element(s) by Class Name

Tags: javascript

Let's estimate that we have elements arranged as below:

```
<div><input class="elementToGet" value="1"></div>           // st elementToGet
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr1
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr2
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr3
<div><input class="elementToGet" value="2"></div>           // nd elementToGet
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr4
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr5
<div><span class"button">get prev elementToGet</span></div> // Nr6
```

How can I get the previous `elementToGet` for each span?

For example the elements numbered from 4 will get the second `elementToGet`.

Javascript with no frameworks needed.

```
function getPrev(className) {
    var items = [], myPosts = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {

        // I have no ideas what to do next

        items.push(myPosts[i]);
    }
    return items[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you read any Javascript documentation or made any attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want, you can use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) to get the `div` around the `span`.  Then you can use [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.previousSibling) to traverse the DOM and use <strike>[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes)</strike> [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild) to find the input you want.

I hacked together this quickly:

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[4], // one of the "button" spans
    div = span.parentNode, // get the span's parent div
    ele,  // variable to hold the element we are looking for
    temp; // temp var for the loop

while ((div = div.previousSibling) !== null) {  // Loop through all the previous divs
    temp = div.firstChild;  // get the div's children
    if (temp && temp.className === 'elementToGet') { // does it's 1st child have the class?
        ele = temp;  // we found it!
        break;
    }
}
alert(ele.value);​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zH4SU/1/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I were trying to achieve it by a harder and non-sense way.

Comment: actually from his description it seems like .closest() would work, except no frameworks allowed

Comment: @ScottC: `.closest` only searches the parents of an element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery you could use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), it traverses up the DOM tree

Comment: That's one method that's needed, but this alone will not get the element the OP is looking for.