# Get previous and next elements by class name in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have html like this.

```js
function update(elem) {
  var value = elem.value;
  var previousChildren = elem.previousElementSibling;

  if (previousChildren) {
    previousChildren.value = value - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="price from" class="from" name='from1' onkeyup="update(this);">
  <input readonly type="text" placeholder="price to" class="to" name="to1">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="price from" class="from" name='from2' onkeyup="update(this);">
  <input readonly type="text" placeholder="price to" class="to" name='to2' ">
</div>
```

But unsuccessful in getting previous element sibling.

So I need to update `price to` based upon `price from` of the next `div`. i need to fix the range. Problem i am getting is how to get the previous first element with class `to`. Like if i filled element with name `from2` i have to fill `to1` automatically and this goes on with many fields as per the user requirements. I have done this previously in jquery but want to do this in pure javascript and not able to find any good answer.

Comment: Can you add some JS of what have tried so far  and problem you are facing, this question is already answered here on SO. Please create [mre] of problem in SO snipet by pressing <> button in editor.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480886/get-previous-above-elements-by-class-name

Comment: Let me add more description.

Comment: @YuduBan No it is not that i dont want to search for the parent node to be searched i dont have specific parent node in this case. There are only divs and i just want previous first element with class name `to` regardless of the parent node.

Comment: @ikiK No element with name 'to1' should be filled when a user fill element with name `from2`. so i have to search in previous nodes. Also for the next sibling i also want to check some validations but this is the first case to get previous element.

Comment: Yeah got it bit late, this is easy, you get parent `div` of `from2`, get its previous `div`, and guery it for class `to` element...

Comment: This is really about cousins, not siblings. How about ignoring hierarchy altogether and setting values based on names: iterate all of the inputs, and set "from" (for n+1) to be the same as "to" (for n)?

Comment: @ikiK exactly but i am unable to do this in javascript in jquery it have many functions to traverse the previous nodes.

Comment: @danh i put names because of the ease of the readers. I dont want to add names.. Also want to do this as a general coding because a user can add multiple divs which contains range from and range to inputs.

Comment: What will be the behaviour of first row?

Comment: @HassanImam Ho does have `if (previousChildren) {` , so nothing?

Answer (score 0):

get all `<input>` elements inside `<div>` (return `NodeListt`)

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > input')
```

get all `<input>` elements with class `to` inside `<div>` (return `NodeListt`)

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > input.to')
```

Other logic is pretty simple:

```js
// for example get element from2
current_element = document.querySelector('div > input[name=from2]')

// get all elements
node_list = document.querySelectorAll('div > input')

// search previous element position in nodelist
node_list.forEach((element, index) => {if (element.getAttribute('name') === current_element.getAttribute('name')) index_for_search = (index-1)})
console.log(index_for_search)

// get element by position
element_to_search = node_list[index_for_search]
```

Comment: I dont want all elements just a previous element with class name `to`.

Answer (score 0):

Like i mentioned in comment you can use this:

```
elem.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".to");
```

```js
function update(elem) {
  var value = elem.value;
  var previousChildren = elem.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".to");
  if (previousChildren) {
    previousChildren.value = value - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="price from" class="from" name='from1' onkeyup="update(this);">
  <input readonly type="text" placeholder="price to" class="to" name="to1">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="price from" class="from" name='from2' onkeyup="update(this);">
  <input readonly type="text" placeholder="price to" class="to" name='to2'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can i know how to get the next element too? Also is there any way we can do that without getting parent node. Just like we do in jquery function where it get the first element without specifying the parent node.